# How to get time to arduino from NTP through esp8266

Tags: arduino, esp8266, arduino-esp8266

I am trying to get time from a NTP server to my Arduino using an ESP8266 module.

1. How can I achieve this?
2. Do I have to upload code directly to the ESP8266 or Arduino?

Comment: You are interested in other things besides your local time?

Comment: actually i just need to get time from a NTP server so that i can display time and date using an arduino.

Answer (score -1):

You can upload the code via arduino. when you upload the code you have to GND the GPIO0 port in order to enable flashing.